# Php, error to loop result of mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

While Selecting data from the row, i'm getting the error 
***Notice: Undefined index: password*** 

Here is the Code:

```
$query = "SELECT username and password FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $hash= $row["password"];
}
```

Thanks for answering

Comment: That isn't the only thing wrong here.  That isn't how SELECT'ing multiple columns work. Do spend the time to read and undertand the manual on this. You're also mixing apis.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you tell me how many things are wrong here?

Comment: "SELECT username`,`password FROM users WHERE username='$username'"`

Answer (score 0):

This Query must returns only one row, you don't need any loop here, if the username is unique. Try to connect to database with `OOP(object oriented programming)` like this, example:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db-name"); mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'utf8');
$query= $mysqli->query("SELECT username,password FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'");
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$hash= $row["password"];
```

Comment: And this gives the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string

Comment: Try to `echo $username` check if it's not empty before the query!

Comment: Have you edited the seperator in `SELECT username,password` to comma (`,`)not `and`?

Comment: It echo's correctly!, I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: Yes i replaced the comma with the and

Comment: hey i got the answer, You told me to use `$row = $query->fetch_assoc();` but it's actually `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: But I don't have `$result` in my example

Comment: You should've taken it from my example. Actually the `fetch_assoc();` needs a `query` and the `con` variable which we use to connect to the database i think

Comment: you are using old mysqli script, my example is better, this used no one more

Comment: I don't think so, as i use mysqli and most of the new things in php 7

Comment: you can just ask about it.

Comment: Okay then tell me the new way to do it

Comment: Take my example copy and edit databasse informations only. [and learn more here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: i took your example only and i got the error and i fixed it man

Comment: i can't understand your english please elaborate